# Intel Assembly ljmp syntax from AT&T syntax

Tags: assembly, x86-16, gnu-assembler, att, intel-syntax

I am trying to convert the xv6 boot code from At&t syntax to Intel syntax and I have a problem with the ljmp instruction. I am trying to learn the boot process of Intel computers and I am not particularly strong with Intel assembly.

The original AT&T syntax is `ljmp $0x8, $start32`.

Minimal example:

```
.code16
   jmp 0x8:start32          # won't assemble

.code32
start32:
   nop
```

Using `as -32 -msyntax=intel -mnaked-reg foo.s` with GNU Binutils 2.35.1 produces
`Error: junk ':start32' after expression` for the far jmp line.

I am using GNU as, and gcc tools.
There might also be other problems with the assembly such as the gdtdesc and gdt.

The full code ported to Intel syntax is:

```
# Start the first CPU: switch to 32-bit protectied mode, jump into C.
# The BIOS loads this code from the first sector of the hard disk into
# memory at physical address 0x7c00 and starts executing in real mode
# with cs = 0 and ip = 7c00.
.code16
.global start
start:
    # Disable interrupts.
    cli

    # Zero data segment registers DS, ES, and SS.
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax

seta20.1:
    # Wait for not busy.
    in al, 0x64
    test al, 0x2
    jnz seta20.1

    # 0xd1 -> port 0x64
    mov al, 0xd1
    out 0x64, al

seta20.2:
    # Wait for not busy.
    in al, 0x64
    test al, 0x2
    jnz seta20.2

    # 0xdf -> port 0x60
    mov al, 0xdf
    out 0x60, al

    # Switch from real to protected mode. Use a bootstrap GDT that makes
    # virtual addresses map directly to physical addressses so that the
    # effective memory map doesn't change during the transition.
    lgdt gdtdesc

    # Protection Enable in cr0 register.
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 0x1
    mov cr0, eax

    # Complete the transtion to 32-bit protected mode by using a long jmp
    # to reload cs and eip. The segment descriptors are set up with no
    # translation, so that the mapping is still the identity mapping.

    # This instruction giving me problems.
    ljmp start32, 0x8

.code32
start32:
    # Set up the protected-mode data segment registers
    mov ax, 0x10
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax

    # Zero the segments not ready for use.
    xor ax, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    # Set up the stack pointer and call into C.
    mov esp, start
    call bootmain

    # If bootmain returns spin.. ??
spin:
    hlt
    jmp spin

# Bootstrap GDT set up null segment, code segment, and data segment respectively.
# Force 4 byte alignment.
.p2align 2
gdt:
    .word 0x0000, 0x0000
    .byte 0, 0, 0, 0
    .word 0xffff, 0x0000
    .byte 0, 0x9a, 0xcf, 0
    .word 0xffff, 0x0000
    .byte 0, 0x92, 0xcf, 0

# sizeof(gdt) - 1 and address of gdt respectively.
gdtdesc:
    .word (gdtdesc - gdt - 1)
    .long gdt
```

Comment: You want `jmp 0x8:start32`. PS: atat is the star wars walker, the syntax is at&t :)

Comment: My bad haha. Using jmp 0x8:start32 produces 'Error: junk ':start32' after expression' using GNU as.

Comment: Assembles fine here using `as` version 2.28. What do you have? Alternatively you can try `ljmp 0x8, start32` but that is not really intel syntax but it does seem to assemble in intel syntax mode.

Comment: I am using as version 2.35. I tried ljmp 0x8, start32 which compiles but it seems to stall after the instruction. Maybe the stall suggests other problems with the assembly? I'm not 100% sure the gdt and gdtdesc is correct.

Comment: Verify the generated machine code, e.g. using `as -al` or a disassembler. It should be `EA 31 00 08 00` (the `31` may vary that's the address of `start32`).

Comment: objdump -S: 36: ea 3f 00 08 00

Comment: That looks about right before linking. However, since your boot sector is loaded at `0x7c00` in the final boot sector that should be relocated to `0x7c3f`. Make sure you are linking with a base address of `0x7c00`.

Comment: In the Makefile: ld -Ttext 0x7C00 (-other args...). Like that? I might have to set up a debugger to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Yes, that should do it.

Comment: When I read a 32 bit bootloader, that single instruction had to be encoded manually with db. There might be a way to say it, but it defeats me.

Comment: It still seems to spin after that instruction.

Comment: It can't really "spin". Either it jumps to somewhere or it faults. Unless you mean the `spin` label, but that is way past the `jmp` already. Anyway, this is not a [mcve], [edit] your question if you'd like us to give a try.

Comment: Actually the code is working now! It jumps to bootmain() (which is in c). I added some code that would fault the CPU in bootmain(). So there is something in bootmain() that is causing it to not progress in the boot process (it doesn't fault the CPU). So adding ljmp 0x8, start32 fixed the code. But you mentioned that is not really Intel syntax. Is there an equivalent that would be Intel syntax?

Comment: The `jmp 0x8:start32` which assembles for me, and produces the same machine code. Also works with `as` 2.33.1. I don't have 2.35 right now.

Comment: I'll have to leave it as is for now, unfortunately it gives me an error. I'll leave jmp 0x8:start32 as a comment in the code for later though. I would like to have the assembly be as portable as it can be between different assemblers. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jester: I'm not sure that's the actual right instruction. That will leave cs as 16 bit thus running 32 bit code with a 16 bit IP register. It's not invalid, but you're really supposed to be in that mode for only a few instructions while you finish setting up 32 bit mode.

Comment: Since there is a mix of 16 and 32-bit assembly code should the tag be x86-16 or x86?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use `jmp 0x08, start32`**

For some reason, `jmp 0x8:start32`  only works after `.intel_syntax noprefix`, even with command line args that should be equivalent.  This is the syntax used by Binutils `objdump -d -Mintel -mi8086`, e.g. `ea 16 00 08 00    jmp  0x8:0x16` so it's probably a GAS bug that it's not accepted sometimes.

---

I edited your question to create a small reproducible example with `as` 2.35.1 (which I have on Arch GNU/Linux) based on your comments replying to Jester.  I included command line options:  I assume you must have been using those because there's no `.intel_syntax noprefix` directive in your file.

**That seems to be the problem: `-msyntax=intel -mnaked-reg` makes other Intel syntax things work, like `xor ax,ax`, but does *not* make `jmp 0x8:start32` work** (or other ways of writing it).  Only a `.intel_syntax noprefix`<sup>1</sup> directive makes that syntax for far jmp work.

```
# .intel_syntax noprefix        # rely on command line options to set this
.code16
   xor  ax, ax              # verify that command-line setting of intel_syntax worked, otherwise this line errors.

   ljmp 0x8, start32        # Working before or after a syntax directive, but is basically AT&T syntax
#   jmp 0x8:start32          # fails here, works after a directive
   jmp 0x8, start32         # Michael Petch's suggested syntax that's still somewhat AT&Tish.  works with just cmdline opts. 

.att_syntax
   ljmp $0x8, $start32      # working everywhere, even with clang
.intel_syntax noprefix
   jmp 0x8:start32          # objdump disassembly syntax, but only works after a .intel_syntax noprefix directive

.code32
start32:
   nop
```

I verified that `-msyntax=intel -mnaked-reg` work for other instructions where their effect is necessary: `movzx  ax, al` works.  But without `-mnaked-reg` we'd get "too many memory references" because "ax" and "al" would be taken as symbol names.  Without  or "operand size mismatch" without `-msyntax=intel`.

**A GAS listing** from `as -32 -msyntax=intel -mmnemonic=intel -mnaked-reg -o foo.o  foo.s   -al --listing-lhs-width=2 --listing-rhs-width=140`
(I'm pretty sure `-mmnemonic=intel` is irrelevant, and implied by syntax=intel.)

Note that you can see which instructions worked because they have machine code, and which didn't (the first `jmp 0x8:start32`) because the left-hand column is empty for it.  The very first column would normally be addresses, but is ???? because assembly failed.  (Because I uncommented the `jmp 0x8:start32` to show it failing the first time, working the 2nd time.)

```
foo.s: Assembler messages:
foo.s:6: Error: junk `:start32' after expression
GAS LISTING foo.s                       page 1


   1                            # .intel_syntax noprefix        # rely on command line options to set this
   2                            .code16
   3 ???? 0FB6C0                   movzx   ax, al              # verify that command-line setting of intel_syntax worked, otherwise this line errors.
   4                       
   5 ???? EA170008 00              ljmp 0x8, start32        # Working before or after a syntax directive, but is basically AT&T syntax
   6                               jmp 0x8:start32          # fails here, works after a directive
   7 ???? EA170008 00              jmp 0x8, start32         # Michael Petch's suggested syntax that's still somewhat AT&Tish.  works with just cmdline opts. 
   8                       
   9                            .att_syntax
  10 ???? EA170008 00              ljmp $0x8, $start32      # working everywhere, even with clang
  11                            .intel_syntax noprefix
  12 ???? EA170008 00              jmp 0x8:start32          # objdump disassembly syntax, but only works after a .intel_syntax noprefix directive
  13                       
  14                            .code32
  15                            start32:
  16 ???? 90                       nop
  17
```

(GAS does listing field widths for the left column in "words", which apparently means 32-bit chunks.  That's why the `00` most-significant byte of the segment selector is separated by a space.)

Putting a label *before* the `jmp 0x8:label` didn't help; it's not an issue of forward vs. backward reference.  Even `jmp 0x8:23` fails to assemble.

---

Syntax "recommended" by disassemblers, from a working build:

`objdump -drwC -Mintel -mi8086  foo.o` :

```
foo.o:     file format elf32-i386

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <start32-0x17>:
   0:   0f b6 c0                movzx  ax,al
   3:   ea 17 00 08 00          jmp    0x8:0x17 4: R_386_16     .text
   8:   ea 17 00 08 00          jmp    0x8:0x17 9: R_386_16     .text
   d:   ea 17 00 08 00          jmp    0x8:0x17 e: R_386_16     .text
  12:   ea 17 00 08 00          jmp    0x8:0x17 13: R_386_16    .text

00000017 <start32>:
  17:   90                      nop
```

`llvm-objdump --mattr=+16bit-mode --x86-asm-syntax=intel -d foo.o` :

```
00000000 <.text>:
       0: 0f b6 c0                      movzx   ax, al
       3: ea 17 00 08 00                ljmp    8, 23
       8: ea 17 00 08 00                ljmp    8, 23
       d: ea 17 00 08 00                ljmp    8, 23
      12: ea 17 00 08 00                ljmp    8, 23

00000017 <start32>:
      17: 90                            nop
```

And BTW, I didn't get clang 11.0 to assemble any Intel-syntax versions of this with a symbol name.  `ljmp 8, 12` assembles with clang, but not even `ljmp 8, start32`.  Only by switching to AT&T syntax and back could I get clang's built-in assembler (`clang -m32 -masm=intel -c`) to emit a 16-bit mode far jmp.

```
.att_syntax
   ljmp $0x8, $start32      # working everywhere, even with clang
.intel_syntax noprefix
```

Keep in mind this direct form of far JMP is not available in 64-bit mode; perhaps that's why LLVM's built-in assembler appears to have spent less effort on it.

---

Footnote 1: Actually `.intel_syntax prefix` works, too, but never use that.  Nobody want to see the franken-monster that is `mov %eax, [%eax]`, or especially `add %edx, %eax` that's using `dst, src` order, but with AT&T decorated register names.

Comment: Thanks! I added the .intel_syntax noprefix and jmp 0x8:start32 to the code for now. I'll remove the .intel_syntax noprefix later when the bug is patched.

Comment: @cbot: or keep it so you don't need to type annoying obscure command-line options.  A syntax directive at the top of a file generally simplifies things for everyone dealing with your file, and is the standard way to use Intel Syntax with GAS.

Comment: I didn't mention it in the question but I am trying to keep the code and assembly as portable as possible. I am trying to remove all the inline assembly which forces reliance on compilers like GCC and Clang. I also would like the assembly to be as portable as possible among assemblers if that is even achievable. I might end up switching to NASM instead of GNU as. Would NASM still compile the .intel_syntax or would it give me an error?

Comment: @cbot: No, NASM wouldn't accept `.intel_syntax noprefix`.  But it also wouldn't accept `.word` (use `dw` instead), or `.p2align`.  NASM directives are completely different from GAS.  Also, in NASM syntax, `mov bx, symbol` is a `mov`-immediate, while in GAS you need `mov bx, OFFSET symbol` otherwise it's a load.  So even for instructions, there's no way to write asm that assembles correctly with both GAS and NASM.  (Unless you do `%define OFFSET  ` (as the empty string) in NASM's preprocessor.  Which you could actually do with a `-DOFFSET=`  on the command line...)

Comment: I would prefer the syntax that is closed to what the manufacturer specifies. Would NASM like assemblers be the closest then?

Comment: @cbot: Intel's and AMD's manuals only specify syntax for instructions (not directives), and don't specify anything about how syntax for symbols works.  Your goal makes a little bit of sense for instructions themselves, e.g. wanting to write `jmp seg:off` to match the manual's `jmp ptr16:16` form (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jmp).  That makes it easy to look up instructions in the manual. But beyond that, it's a pointless exercise; what matters is compat with software someone might actually want to use to assemble.

Comment: @cbot:  That said, NASM is an objectively good well-designed assembler and syntax IMO, and has a flat-binary output mode that makes it easy to do stuff like legacy BIOS bootloaders without having to mess around with a linker.  (Just use an ORG directive.)

Comment: @cbot: However, if you want to also use any GNU C inline asm, AT&T syntax is a good choice, and GNU intel-syntax is also good.  You can't use NASM for inline asm, and it's best if the whole project uses the same asm syntax.

Comment: I don't want to use inline assembly. I want to try and keep the C compiler portable as possible. I'll stick with GNU as assembler for now but, in the future I will have to think about what assembly syntax to use.

Comment: @cbot: Doesn't xv6 have any inline asm?  Or does it purely make calls to separately-assembled files for instructions like `invlpg [edi]` or `mov cr3, eax`?  If the latter, then yes you could in theory port everything over to NASM syntax, but I don't see a compelling reason to do so.

Comment: It does have inline assembly but I want to remove it. I'm trying to make it compile with any C compiler such as the Tiny C Compiler (tcc). There is a mix some are fully separate assembly files and some are inline assembly. It is also all written in AT&T syntax and I am not a huge fan of that syntax.

Answer (score 6):

In the complete translated code you presented, this line is incorrect:

```
ljmp start32, 0x8
```

The proper syntax for a FAR JMP in GNU Assembler's Intel syntax is:

```
ljmp 0x08, start32
```

The selector value would be first and the offset second. It seems in translating from AT&T syntax you reversed these 2 values when the order should have remained the same. With the values reversed you would have got the error `Error: can't handle non absolute segment in 'ljmp'`. In GNU Assembler's Intel syntax you can also substitute `ljmp` with `jmp` so `jmp 0x08, start32` would work as well.

There are different flavors of Intel syntax. `jmp 0x8:start32` is NASM's Intel syntax and it differs from GNU Assembler's Intel syntax where the `:` and `,` differ. If you used a `:` to separate the two values you would get the error `Error: junk ':start32' after expression` in GNU Assembler.

---

### Notes

- If the code in `bootmain` doesn't work it is likely an issue unrelated to the bootloader code you presented in this question. If you are also building all the *C* code with Intel Syntax rather than AT&T syntax, then make sure all the inline assembly has been properly converted as source and operand would have been reversed as well. xv6 likely has inline assembly in a number of files including `xv6-public/x86.h`, `xv6-public/spinlock.c`, `xv6-public/usertests.c` and `xv6-public/stressfs.c`

Comment: `jmp 0x8:start32` works in GAS after `.intel_syntax noprefix`, but not with command line options.  See my answer for a listing showing this.  This is probably a GAS bug.

Comment: I added the .intel_syntax noprefix and jmp 0x8:start32 and it works. I am considering switching to NASM. I have the xv6 code all separated into boot/, kern/, user/libc/, and user/bin/. Right now I am looking at the bootloader currently. The bootmain.c problem seems to be in the inline assembly but I do not specify any flags that would modify the assembly syntax used by gcc. I am going to look closer into the disassembly of bootmain().

Comment: I looked at the disassembly and the inline assembly seems to compile fine to machine code. But it still faults the CPU. This also happened when I was working on switching the .S files to .s files in the kernel. I might need to set up a debugger to see whats happening.

Comment: @cbot : Do you have your project on Github or some place we can look at it? Debugging it in BOCHs or maybe even QEMU/GDB is a good idea. You should be able to find the faulting instruction. As it stands the code you showed here enters 32-bit protected mode properly. I happened to test it here. Did you make other changes to the xv6 code in any way?

Comment: Mostly segmented the code up into a boot/, kern/, user/libc/, and user/bin/. I also changed a few .S files to .s and changed some of the indentation from spaces to tabs. The end goal is to move all inline assembly and .S files to .s and change the indentation. Then build a system from there. I can put the project on Github today but I just want to clean a few things up in it.

Comment: Added the xv6 code to github: https://github.com/christianchabot/xv6-small

Comment: @cbot I didn't investigate much but I do know for a fact that it is failing the moment kern/entry.S   enables paging. The `info tab` command in bochs suggests the reason for this is that the address put in CR3 doesn't point to a valid paging structure and because of that there are no mapping available so the moment you enable paging the cpu fault.

Comment: it appears to me that `entrypgdi`r was never loaded into memory so memory is all filled with zeroes so there is no page structure.

Comment: Could it be that xv6 uses 4MB pages which is a pentium extension which would cause a i386 processor to fault? I don't know why it would not be working because I did not touch any of the entry.S or main.c code. The code uses the entrypgdir in the main.c. I am having a hard time getting GDB to work with QEMU so I can't really take a look myself yet.

Comment: @cbot QEMU supports large (4MiB) pages in its i386 non-PAE implementation. When I look at the memory where `entrypgdir` is suppose to be the entire 4096 bytes of that table are all 0. There should be something in the firts entry and one later on. I can see them defined in main, and the only thing I can think of is that your bootmain didn't load the entire program into memory. I haven't had the time to look in depth at the problem. The problem is that there are effectively no page table entries so there is no mapping. That is the problem.

Comment: The code now runs fine when I use the default system tools (x86_64-linux-gnu with flags to turn off system libraries, etc). But when I switch the tools to the (i386-elf with system libraries searching turned off) tools that I compiled the code faults. It must be doing that depending on which tools I am using because it now works fine.